# Block javascript on specific websites in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript

I'm looking for a way to block javascript for specific websites in Internet Explorer, like YesScript does in Mozilla Firefox. Is there a plugin or a way to do this? It seems like this is not possible in IE.

Comment: @Ramhound please see my answer.

Comment: Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer go to:

- Tools -> Internet Options
- Security Tab
- Click on Restricted Sites
- Click the Sites button
- Type in a URL you want to block and click the Add button

  - I used `*.stackoverflow.com`
- Close
- Apply/OK
- Visit http://stackoverflow.com

Make sure your settings match what I have screen-capped below. Good luck!

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

If you are interested as to why this method works then select Restricted Sites, press the `Custom level...` button, and scroll down to this section:

[image]

Comment: This is not working as expected. Javascript is disabled, but the site is all messed up now. When I only disable Javascript, the design of the website is still ok. So it's blocking/disabling to much.

Comment: @Jente You will have to adjust settings in the `Custom level...` until you get the desired results.